# ng-keypress, ng-keyup, ng-keydown not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

I have this piece of code in angular 1.4.7:

```
<input ng-keypress="console.log('press');" required="" class="form-control" ng-model="item" name="item" ng-disabled="reviewMode === 'REVIEW'" placeholder="Item">
```

The console.log('press') does not fire on any key pressed. I tried to use keyup and keydown also and they don't work either.

I know that an element needs to have the tabindex property for ng-keypress to work, I tried adding that property, even tough it's an input element (still doesn't work).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to use the `console.log` direct in the HTML, the AngularJS looking in the scope for a function.

Take a look in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ksevksev/Sj4ZU/).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that one :)

Answer (score 0):

`ng-keypress` is angular built in directive that meant for execute scope functions and expressions. Angular does't allow to execute alerts or console logs like this. you need to create a scope function and put console.log() inside that function in order to execute console log